# Problemas Crud PHP MYSQL JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

Estoy realizando un CRUD con PHP, MySQL y otras herramientas para poder poblar mi tabla de información generado desde un JSON pero he probado varias maneras y no he podido poblar la informaión requerida. Me gustaria contar con ayuda para saber que hago mal.

En mi indice ademas del problema de llenar mi table tengo el problema que al apretar el button sumbit este me carga mi backend donde realizo las diferentes consultas.

index.php

```
<?php include "conn.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <head>
        <?php include("head.php");?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
                        <i class="icon-reorder shaded"></i></a><a class="brand" href="/visorpartes" >Visor Parte Digital</a>
                   
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /navbar-inner -->
        </div><br />

            <div class="container">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Busqueda de partes malos</h3> 
            <form class="" action="tester.php" method='get' id="busqueda" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>

      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-10 form-group">
          <label for="name" class="control-label">Unidad policial</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unidad_policial" name="unidad_policial" value='' placeholder="Unidad policial">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-check">
                <label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ver_malo" name="ver_malo" value="1" > Ver parte malo
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12  form-group">
        <div class="">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick='resetForm($("#busqueda"));'>Cancelar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
<table id="informe" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-mid" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Archivo</th>
              <th>Fecha</th>
              <th>Estado</th>
              <th>Paso actual</th>
              <th>Ruta respaldo</th>
              <th class="text-center"> Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Archivo</th>
              <th>Fecha</th>
              <th>Estado</th>
              <th>Paso actual</th>
              <th>Ruta respaldo</th>
              <th class="text-center"> Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>









                
            <!--/.container-->
        
        <!--/.wrapper--><br />
        <div class="footer span-12">
            <div class="container">
              <center> <b class="copyright"><a href="http://bpt.cl"> Blue Peaks SpA</a> &copy; <?php echo date("Y")?> Visor Parte Digital </b></center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        
        <script src="datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script>
        
        function resetForm($form){
                $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
                $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAtrr('selected');
            }

        
        </script>
      
    </body>
```

En el index.php tengo problema en el sumbit ya que me realiza una carga al metodo tester.php y no refresca mi table ademas que no logro cargar la información a mi indice.

tester.php

```
<?php

 include "conn.php";

/* Database connection end */


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
//$requestData= $_REQUEST;
$unidad_policial= $_GET['unidad_policial'];
$ver_malo= $_GET['ver_malo'];
//$unidad_policial=(isset($_REQUEST["unidad_policial"]) && $_REQUEST["unidad_policial"]!="");
//$ver_malos=(isset($_REQUEST["ver_malo"]) && $_REQUEST["ver_malo"]!="" ? $_REQUEST["ver_malo"] : 600);
//echo $unidad_policial;
$ver=isset($_GET['ver_malo']) ? "1" : "0";

$where="";
$where.= "WHERE paso_actual IN ('3-EN ERROR', '4-EN MALOS') ";

if($ver=="1"){
    $where.= " AND ver_malo = 'L'";
}

//$unidad_policial=$_REQUEST['unidad_policial'];
if(isset($unidad_policial) && $unidad_policial!="" or is_not_null($unidad_policial)){
    $where.=" AND unidad_policial LIKE '".$unidad_policial."%' ";
}

$from=" FROM archivo ";

$query="SELECT id, nombre_archivo, created_at, estado, paso_actual, ruta_respaldo $from $where";

$query=$query. " ORDER BY unidad_policial DESC";
//echo $query;

$sql=mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die;

$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 

    $nestedData[] = $row["id"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["nombre_archivo"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["created_at"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["estado"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["paso_actual"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["ruta_respaldo"];
    $nestedData[] = '<td><center>
                     
                     <a href="visualiza.php?path='.$row['ruta_respaldo'].'&file='.$row['nombre_archivo'].'"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> <i class="menu-icon icon-file"></i> </a>

                     <a href="actualizar.php?id='.$row['id'].'"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"> <i class="menu-icon icon-edit"></i> </a>
                     </center></td>';       
    
    $data[] = $nestedData;
    //action="update-edit.php" method="POST"
    //<a href="editar.php?id='.$row['id'].'"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"> <i class="menu-icon icon-file"></i> </a>
}



$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

En este archivo realizo la conexión a mi db y entrego la informacíon de la consulta realizada pero como explico tengo problema al cargar la tabla con jquery ya que no me manejo de buena manera me gustaria contar con ayuda y asi poder aprender mas

Comment: Si no quieres que la página se recargue tienes que usar Ajax para ello. En cuanto al otro problema que indicas, ¿has depurado algo? ¿con qué resultados?

Comment: cuando veo preguntas con "no me funciona el código" o sin un mínimo esfuerzo de depurar el error... tiendo a no dejar comentario pero hare una excepción ... y preguntare que has intentado???

Comment: he intentado agrgar "ajax":{
      url :"tester.php", // json datasource
      type: "post",  // method  , by default get
      error: function(){  // error handling
       $(".lookup-error").html("");
       $("#lookup").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');

Comment: A. Cedano he depurado mi tester.php y obtengo los resultados requeridos pero no he logrado realizar la entrega de dato a mi tabla de index.php como le comentaba a Francisco Nuñez he probado realizar la obtencion de los datos utilizando jquery pero no me muestra la info

Comment: Esto es lo que me entrega el json {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":22996,"recordsFiltered":22996,"data":[["1792903","13COM66-00-01_20190902_18153127_1.pdf","2019-09-02 18:15:35","ERROR","4-EN MALOS","\/Repositorio\/respaldo_preproceso\/2019-09-02","

Answer (score 0):

Modifique mi index.php pero me aparece un input de busqueda ademas de que aun no obtengo los parametros del form que cree

```
<?php include "conn.php"; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <head>
        <?php include("head.php");?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
                        <i class="icon-reorder shaded"></i></a><a class="brand" href="/visorpartes" >Visor Parte Digital</a>
                   
                   
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /navbar-inner -->
        </div><br />

            <div class="container">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Busqueda de partes malos</h3> 
            <form class="" action="parte.php" method='get' id="busqueda" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>

      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-10 form-group">
          <label for="name" class="control-label">Unidad policial</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unidad_policial" name="unidad_policial" value='' placeholder="Unidad policial">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-check">
                <label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ver_malo" name="ver_malo" value="1" > Ver parte malo
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12  form-group">
        <div class="">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick='resetForm($("#busqueda"));'>Cancelar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
<table id="informe" class="table table-bordered table-hover">  
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Archivo</th>
              <th>Fecha</th>
              <th>Estado</th>
              <th>Paso actual</th>
              <th>Ruta respaldo</th>
              <th class="text-center"> Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
</tbody>
            
    </table>
</div>









                
            <!--/.container-->
        
        <!--/.wrapper--><br />
        <div class="footer span-12">
            <div class="container">
              <center> <b class="copyright"><a href="http://bpt.cl"> Blue Peaks SpA</a> &copy; <?php echo date("Y")?> Visor Parte Digital </b></center>
            </div>
        </div>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
            
            var dataTable = $('#informe').DataTable( {
              
             "language":    {
              "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
              "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
              "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
              "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
              "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
              "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
              "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
              "sInfoPostFix":    "",
              "sSearch":         "Busqueda unidad policial",
              "sUrl":            "",
              "sInfoThousands":  ",",
              "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
              "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "Primero",
                "sLast":     "Último",
                "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
              },
              "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
              }
            },
    
              "processing": true,
              "serverSide": true,
              "ajax":{
                url :"tester.php", // json datasource
                type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                error: function(){  // error handling
                  $(".lookup-error").html("");
                  $("#lookup").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
                  $("#lookup_processing").css("display","none");
                  
                }
              }
            } );
          } );
</script>
      
    </body>
```